# gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, apt

I'm trying to install this python module, which requires compilation (on Ubuntu 16.04). I'm struggling to understand exactly what's causing it stall; what am I missing?

```
(xenial)chris@localhost:~$ pip install swigibpy
Collecting swigibpy
  Using cached swigibpy-0.4.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: swigibpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for swigibpy ... error
  Complete output from command /home/chris/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-162vhh_i/swigibpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmptqb6ctskpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying swigibpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  running build_ext
  building '_swigibpy' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/IB
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/IB/PosixSocketClient
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DIB_USE_STD_STRING=1 -IIB -IIB/PosixSocketClient -IIB/Shared -I/home/chris/anaconda3/include/python3.5m -c IB/PosixSocketClient/EClientSocketBase.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/IB/PosixSocketClient/EClientSocketBase.o -Wno-switch
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for swigibpy
  Running setup.py clean for swigibpy
Failed to build swigibpy
Installing collected packages: swigibpy
  Running setup.py install for swigibpy ... error
    Complete output from command /home/chris/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-162vhh_i/swigibpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yv9u0wok-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying swigibpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    running build_ext
    building '_swigibpy' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/IB
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/IB/PosixSocketClient
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DIB_USE_STD_STRING=1 -IIB -IIB/PosixSocketClient -IIB/Shared -I/home/chris/anaconda3/include/python3.5m -c IB/PosixSocketClient/EClientSocketBase.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/IB/PosixSocketClient/EClientSocketBase.o -Wno-switch
    gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/chris/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-162vhh_i/swigibpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yv9u0wok-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-162vhh_i/swigibpy/
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The routine commands that saved me time after time for such errors:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install gcc python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev g++
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Only the g++ part is necessary.

Answer (score 78):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: Also, ensure that the gcc and g++ is having same version.

Comment: sudo apt-get install gcc g++

Answer (score 22):

[This](https://www.unixmen.com/fix-gcc-error-trying-exec-cc1plus-execvp-file-directory-fedora/) link helped me to fix this issue.

You need to run below command to get g++ installed

`yum install gcc-c++`

Comment: The question is about an Ubuntu system (hence apt-get for installation), not fedora.

Comment: @emher Could still be helpful to others that come here since the title or tags do not mention Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. 

OS: `Fedora Server 29` 

Command: `dnf install -y gcc-c++`

Comment: @Sourabh Jain: It did, actually, it seems to have moved me one step ahead in my quest for setting up fastText on Amazon Linux (https://stackoverflow.com/q/73712537/1091386) I'll answer there and quote you - if you want some points, please feel free to answer there and I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 8):

For Conda environments the following should help:

```
conda install gcc_linux-64
conda install gxx_linux-64
```

See an old discussion about this issue [here](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3080).

Comment: I had gcc-c++ already installed but the error was still there. This fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: I'd add that it may be useful to run `ln ~/.conda/envs/<your_env>/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc /home/grybouilli/.conda/envs/<your_env>/bin/gcc` and `ln ~/.conda/envs/<your_env>/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-g++ /home/grybouilli/.conda/envs/<your_env>/bin/g++` to ensure that `gcc file.c` and other similar command will use your conda gcc version. Make sure to replace <your_env> with whatever conda environment name you're using

Answer (score 7):

That helped me to build Python greenlet on Docker alpine

```sh
apk add g++
```

Answer (score 1):

On SUSE I used

```
sudo zypper install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 0):

You need build tools. In Ubuntu, use:

```bash
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL / Almalinux / CentOS and clones:

```
dnf install gcc-c++
```