# How to install pyodbc python library in server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I have python 3.8 and I am trying to install pyodbc library to connect sql server but getting error. Please help me how to install it? Is there any other library to connect sql server?

I am using below command -

```
python3 -m pip install pyodbc
```

Error I am getting-

```
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.30.tar.gz (266 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-67s6uwc7
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/
  Complete output (10 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pyodbc' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/app/python3.7.4/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
  gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
  Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-w_eqzv_4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/python3.7.4/include/python3.7m/pyodbc
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/app/python3.7.4/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
    gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-fnygoose/pyodbc_7db1b044e510447c8352fe2f54d4cbe0/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-w_eqzv_4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/python3.7.4/include/python3.7m/pyodbc Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455741/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1plus-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: How do I get g++?

Comment: I am trying to run pip install g++ but getting error.

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install#installing-on-linux

Comment: @Shivika - Please [edit] your question to show the command you are using to try and install the compiler, along with the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the first dependency.

```
!apt install unixodbc-dev --yes
!pip install pyodbc
```